# Select Into #Temp From Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a code that looks like this

```
Select * 
Into #DTemp
From
    (Select A, B, C, D
     From 
      T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.I=T2.I
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      T3 ON T2.I = T3.I
      ....
      T6 ON T5.I = T6.I
           WHERE
           A = 'THE'
           AND B LIKE '%YYYY% 
           AND C >= (TIME)
     )
```

But I get an error on the last parenthesis that says "Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Not sure why there's an error in there as my parenthesis are correct.

Comment: You need to add an alias to your derived table: `AND C >= (TIME)) AS A`

Comment: Or just drop the outer query entirely. It adds nothing but confusion to this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quote after `AND B LIKE '%YYYY%`  this. and add alias name after closing `)`
Check arrow pointers in below code

```
Select * 
Into #DTemp
From
    (Select A, B, C, D
     From 
      T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.I=T2.I
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      T3 ON T2.I = T3.I
      ....
      T6 ON T5.I = T6.I
           WHERE
           A = 'THE'
           AND B LIKE '%YYYY%'  //<---
           AND C >= (TIME)
     ) tablenamehere  //<---
```

Comment: why does there need to be tablenamehere at the end of that?

Comment: @EnaVu Because that's how derived tables work, you need to give them an alias

Comment: that is alias name. You tried that subquery behave like a tablename so needs to add a name to that